# Problem in setting dimension using rioxarray set_spatial_dims()

Tags: python, coordinate-system, rioxarray, xarray

I am having trouble setting dimensions in a xarray object.
I have created a xarray object (data, lats, and lons are 2D ndarray) and set a coordinate system as follows, and it is working.

```
da0 = xr.DataArray(
      data = data,
      dims = ["x","y"],
      coords = dict(
            lon = (["x","y"], lons),
            lat = (["x","y"], lats)
      )
)
da = da0.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)
```

However, when I tried to set the spatial dimension for reprojection

```
da.rio.set_spatial_dims("lon", "lat", inplace=True)
```

it raises the following error.

```
   raise DimensionError(
rioxarray.exceptions.DimensionError: x dimension (lon) not found.
```

Why "lon" is not found although "da" has "lon"?
I want to set dimensions for using xr.rio.reproject() in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dims and coords need to have the same name. This should work:

```py
da0 = xr.DataArray(
      data = data,
      dims = ["x","y"],
      coords = dict(
            x = (["x","y"], lons),
            y = (["x","y"], lats)
      )
)
da = da0.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)
```

Comment: Then it raises an error that
`
  raise MissingDimensionsError(
xarray.core.variable.MissingDimensionsError: 'x' has more than 1-dimension and the same name as one of its dimensions ('x', 'y'). xarray disallows such variables because they conflict with the coordinates used to label dimensions.
`

Comment: Even if I change the dimension name to x1, it still raises error 
```
da = xr.DataArray(
      data = data,
      dims = ["x1","y1"],
      coords = dict(
            x = (["x1","y1"], lons),
            y = (["x1","y1"], lats)
      )
)
```
rioxarray.exceptions.DimensionError: x dimension (x) not found.

Comment: rioxarray expects 1D coordinate arrays. I think having 2D coordinate arrays is your problem.

Comment: This might be a helpful reference: https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/issues/209

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!! I will try it

Comment: Actually I realized the grid is evenly-spaced, so flatten the 1st colum and rows of the geo-coordinate arrays worked okay. Your comments helped me a lot to figure it out, thank you very much for quick reseponse!!